# How can I create inline action buttons / labels in code using my VS Code extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What is that appear on every top of a function? How to do that? What is it called?
I'm working on an extension. Anybody who knows how to do this. In the documentation for VS Code, I can't locate any. It is displayed top of every functions.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know . if there is a way to get that ?

Answer (score 1):

That's the CodeLens feature.

In the docs:

- `registerCodeLensProvider(selector: DocumentSelector, provider: CodeLensProvider<CodeLens>): Disposable`
- [`CodeLens`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeLens)
- [`CodeLensProvider<T>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeLensProvider%3CT%3E)

Official sample code can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/codelens-sample/src/CodelensProvider.ts.

There's [a 2017 VS Code blogpost listing some examples of extensions that use the feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup).